# python: pass a dictionary to anther thread using Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, asynchronous, queue

I am passing a dictionary to anther thread using Queue.
I expected to receive two different dictionaries, but I actually received the same dictionary twice. 
I can make a deepcopy to fix the problem, but is there a better way instead of deepcopy everytime?

```
import threading 
from queue import Queue
import time
import copy
q = Queue()

def put(q): 
    d = {}
    d[1] = 2
    print(' send d = {}'.format(d))
    q.put(d)
    # d = copy.deepcopy(d) # uncomment this line to fix the problem
    d.pop(1)
    print(' send again d = {}'.format(d))
    q.put(d)

def get(q): 
    d = q.get()
    print(' received d = {}'.format(d))
    d = q.get()
    print(' received again d = {}'.format(d))

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=put, args=(q,)) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=get, args=(q,)) 
    t1.start() 
    t2.start() 
    t1.join() 
    t2.join() 
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: When you say “the same dictionary twice”, what do you mean? It might be clearer if in your code for `get()` you used two different names for the dictionaries you receive.

Comment: Yuan, i'm pretty sure i solved it, can you check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a threading event, it will continue immediately when your work is done:
Set     exit_thread.set() after your first print. Your second call will not happen until the first call finishes. It finishes immediately, no actual wait time except waiting for the first call to finish so continues instantaneously. This is the fastest way to accomplish what your doing. I hope this helps!

```
import threading 
from queue import Queue
import time
import copy
q = Queue()


exit_thread = threading.Event()

def background_thread():
    while True:
        if exit_thread.wait(timeout=10):
            break

def put(q): 
    d = {}
    d[1] = 2
    print(' send d = {}'.format(d))
    q.put(d)
    # This waits until until q.put(d) is finished. You just need to tell it when to break by
    # using exit_thread.set()
    background_thread()
    # d = copy.deepcopy(d) # uncomment this line to fix the problem
    d.pop(1)
    print(' send again d = {}'.format(d))
    q.put(d)

def get(q): 
    d = q.get()
    # This breaks the timeout function, so no wait time in your case
    exit_thread.set()
    print(' received d = {}'.format(d))
    d = q.get()
    print(' received again d = {}'.format(d))

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=put, args=(q,)) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=get, args=(q,)) 
    t1.start() 
    t2.start() 
    t1.join() 
    t2.join() 
    print("Done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're modifying the same dictionary that you're putting into the queue.  The simple solution here is to directly create a new one.  Here's the modified code...

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
q = Queue()

def put(q): 
    d = {1:2}
    print(' send d = {}'.format(d))
    q.put(d)
    d = {3:4}
    print(' send again d = {}'.format(d))
    q.put(d)

def get(q):
    d = q.get()
    print(' received d = {}'.format(d))
    d = q.get()
    print(' received again d = {}'.format(d))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=put, args=(q,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=get, args=(q,)) 
    t1.start() 
    t2.start() 
    t1.join() 
    t2.join() 
    print("Done!")
```

Technically your original code has a race condition in it.  The `pop` is getting executed before your queue has a chance to send it and get printed by the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your code. This is actually the correct behavior. 
Before the receiver thread received the first message, you have actually modified the dictionary. That's why you receive the empty dictionary twice in the receiver thread. 
I just simulated a delay(2sec), before modifying the dictionary. Now you can see the receiver thread getting both states.

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time
import copy
q = Queue()

def put(q):
    d = {}
    d[1] = 2
    print('send d = {}'.format(d))
    q.put(d)
    # d = copy.deepcopy(d) # uncomment this line to fix the problem
    #Add a 2 sec delay to allow other thread to receive.
    time.sleep(2)
    d.pop(1)
    print(' send again d = {}'.format(d))
    q.put(d)

def get(q):
    d = q.get()
    print(' received d = {}'.format(d))
    d = q.get()
    print(' received again d = {}'.format(d))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=put, args=(q,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=get, args=(q,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    print("Done!")
```

### here is the output

send d = {1: 2} 
 received d = {1: 2}
 send again d = {}
 received again d = {}
Done!

in Messaging context, 2 messages usually would refer to 2 different objects which you can achieve by `deepcopy or dict(d)` .

Hope this helps.